# JavaScript Syntax: Inline Ifs in String Assignment Statements

Tags: javascript

I came across this recently and thought it would make a great SO question.

Suppose you are assigning a string to a local variable and you want to vary it by a simple condition. So you insert an inline if statement into the string:

```
var someCondition = true;
var url = "beginning-" + (someCondition)?('middle'):('other_middle') + "-end";
```

But this doesn't work as expected, the value of url will be "middle", not beginning-middle-end. This statement yields the expected result:

```
var url = "beginning-" + ((someCondition)?('middle'):('other_middle')) + "-end";
```

Best explanation of why this is wins the coveted answer flag!

Comment: This is known as a **ternary operator**.  The following link provides a detailed explanation of operator precendence: http://blog.stchur.com/2006/07/14/the-javascript-ternary-operator/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is of course to do with precedence.

```
var url = "beginning-" + (someCondition)?('middle'):('other_middle') + "-end";
```

is interpreted as:

```
var url = ("beginning-" + (someCondition)) ? ('middle') : (('other_middle') + "-end";)
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because of precedence of operators.

The first example evaluates to:

```
if ("beginning-" + someCondition) {
  url = 'middle';
} else {
  url = 'other_middle' + "-end";
}
```

because the `?` operator has precedence over `+`

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, the third operand of the conditional operator is this:

```
('other_middle') + "-end"
```

You need to wrap the expression evaluated by the conditional operator, and BTW you don't need all those parentheses:

```
var url = "beginning-" + (someCondition ? 'middle' :'other_middle') + "-end";
```

Check [this table](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) of operator precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a problem with operator precedence.

Javascript is interpreting the statement like:

```
IF ("beginning-" + (someCondition)) {
  'middle';
} else {
  'other middle' + "-end";
}
```

("beginning-" + (someCondition)) will be concatenated into a string (eg, "beginning-1") and since it's not null, it will be evaluated as boolean True, so the result will always be 'middle'

Answer (score 0):

If the condition is also the value.

The short-hand `var x = y || z;` should also not be forgotten.

In this case I guess

```
var url = "beginning-" + (middle || 'middle_was_bad') + "-end";
```

Could be useful to some people.